# Retrieve Usergroups from other Domains without using AD CmdLets?

Tags: powershell

I do not have access to Admin Rights hence I cannot install the AD module.

How do I retrieve users' usergroup on different domains without the use of Active Directory? Any ideas? I have access to other domains, but I'm only able to access users in my own domain using this script, but not others.

```
$filedirectory = "C:\Users\x\Desktop\z\Project\test.txt"
$outputdirectory = "C:\Users\x\Desktop\Project\Export.csv"
$allusernames = Get-Content $filedirectory
$groups = ""

$resultarray =@()

foreach ($allusernames in $allusernames) {

$groupObject = new-object PSObject

$currentusername = $allusernames
$groups = ([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($currentusername)").Findone().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1' | out-string

$groupObject | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "User" -Value $currentusername
$groupObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Groups" -Value $groups

$resultarray +=$groupObject

} 

$resultarray | export-csv -Path $outputdirectory -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Speak with your Manager and explain that you need the IT Dept to add the AD Cmdlets to your computer so you can do this piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADSI to specify any domain and built the ADSIsearcher from it, like this:

```
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"LDAP://$domain")
```

Note, that you can also use `GC://` to query a Global Catalog and `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()` to dynamically get the current forest and its domains.

Because you are querying group memberships, please note that the group membership is an attribute of the group, not the user. The `memberof` attribute only shows group memberships of domains of the same domain, if the group is domain local.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ForestName = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Name
$root = [ADSI]"GC://$ForestName"
$Searcher = [ADSISEARCHER]$root
```

This was what I used.